# jQuery post after adding form

Tags: jquery, button, .post

I created a commenting script, when you click anywhere on an img it adds a text area inside a div along with some hidden fields along with a button.

When I click the button nothing happens here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Redpen.io</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var status = false;
        var textboxid = 0;
        var dotid = 0;
        var currentTB;
        var currentDOT;
        var dotSRC = 'dot.png';

        $('img[class=stud]').on('click', function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();

            leftE = (e.clientX - offset.left);
            topE = (e.clientY - offset.top);

            //alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
            //alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
            if(status == false){
                dotup(leftE, topE);
                popup(leftE, topE);
                status = true;
            }
            else{
                $('img[class=dot]').remove();
                $('div[class=tb]').remove();
                status = false;
            }
        });

        var dotup = function(leftE, topE){

            var dot = $('<img src="' + dotSRC + '" width="20px" height="20px" class="dot" />');
            dot.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': (topE - 2),
                'left': (leftE - 2)
            });

            dot.attr('id', 'tb_' + dotid);
            currentDOT = 'tb_' + dotid;

            $('body').append(dot);

            dotid++;
        };

        var popup = function(leftE, topE){

            var textbox = $('<div class="tb"></div>');
            textbox.append('<form name="tb" id="Addtb" method="post" action="add_comment.php"><textarea></textarea><input type="button" id="submitTB" name="submitTB" value="Add Comment" /><input type="hidden" name="leftE" value="' + leftE + '" /><input type="hidden" name="topE" value="' + topE + '" /></form>');

            textbox.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': (topE + 5),
                'left': (leftE + 5)
            });


            textbox.attr('id', 'tb_' + textboxid);
            currentTB = 'tb_' + textboxid;

            $('body').append(textbox);

            textbox.find('textarea').focus();

            textboxid++;

        };


        $("#submitTB").on('click', function(event){

            console.log('button clicked');
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log('hmm not preventing the default');
            $.post('test_add.php', $( "#tb" ).serialize());

            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<img class="stud" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make it easier for people to test?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sp7uoeeq/

Answer (score 0):

The event handler isn't being attached to the button at all, that's the problem. The console provides no error, thus, the script doesn't even get to the point to *try* attaching the handler - hence, neither an error nor an event handler.

The solution is to place the event listener attachment in your `popup` function, where imho it should be in the first place. Just copy-paste

```
$("#submitTB").on('click', function (event) {

        ...

    });
```

into the

```
var popup = function (leftE, topE) { ... }
```

declaration, at the end and it'll work.

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vo3bmbod/1/) forked from yours. *(I commended out the `preventDefault()` line as well, but it has nothing to do with this problem)*.